# Is it possible to check if a question answered has a bounty from Answers list?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Visiting my profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/130929/systempuntoout is it possible to see if a question has a bounty directly from Answers list or do i have to click on every answer to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you currently can't; you'll have to check them one-by-one (or, in the case of an expired bounty that wasn't awarded, you can't at all, unless you look at the asker's reputation graph to check if they set a bounty). But with a little [API magic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/), here are those questions you have answered that have or had a bounty attached:

- [implementing GAE XMPP service as an external component to an existing XMPP server (e.g. ejabberd or OpenFire)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641959)
- [Programatically adding "New Custom Field" To Google Contacts using Google contact API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515117)
- [Looking for a good database structure to achieve Facebook/SO like notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535101)
- [Using urllib2 with SOCKS proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537726)
- [Why don't the images fully display when I convert HTML to PDF with Perl's HTML::HTMLDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536486)

Comment: @balpha Thanks for your reply.How do i check that this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515117 had a bounty?

Comment: @systempuntoout: If you go to the [asker's reputation graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/151679?tab=reputationhistory), you can see a -50 entry for this particular question.